# How to copy a set of numbers from text file

Tags: powershell

I've a text file with the following content:

```
    ---Processing--------------------------
    --------------------------------------- 
Installation ID for: Office 19, Office19ProPlus2019MSDNR_Retail edition:
    740589284218418791604841349389902966367300853905012096424324006
    ---------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------
    ---Exiting-----------------------------
```

I want to copy only the set of numbers
I used that code:

```
powershell -c "$(sls '[0-9]+' OfficeIid.txt -allm).Matches.Value"
```

Output was:

```
19 19 2019
740589284218418791604841349389902966367300853905012096424324006
```

How can I copy only the set of numbers starting from 740 (the number changes)

Comment: Try matching 5 or more digits in your regular expression.

Comment: This should be tagged `PowerShell`. Easiest mod to existing coee would be: `"(sls '[0-9]+' OfficeIid.txt -allm).Matches[-1].Value"`

Comment: @KeithMiller
That one worked perfectly
May I ask you how you managed it to work (I couldn't understand how "Matches[-1]" did the trick)

I also managed it to work through the For loop:
in my example the following code worked perfectly:
 `FOR /F "tokens=6,7* delims=, " %%i in (OfficeIid.txt) do @echo %%k`

Comment: `$matches` is a collection (array). With any array or collection, an index of `-1` retrieves the last element, `-2` the next-to-last, etc. [Accessing and using array elements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7#accessing-and-using-array-elements)

Comment: @KeithMiller Thank you so much, I got it (Your clarification is very perfect, thanks again)

Comment: So one of you should add an answer with the solution. I'll fix the PowerShell tag issue. @KeithMiller

Comment: ^^  One of you should write up an answer with the final solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell:
You current command:

```
"$(sls '[0-9]+' OfficeIid.txt -allm).Matches.Value"
```

returns the value of *every* item in the [$matches](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#matches) collection. Add an index of [`-1`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7#accessing-and-using-array-elements) to return only the last match:

```
"(sls '[0-9]+' OfficeIid.txt -allm).Matches[-1].Value"
```

Data/Output:

```
PS C:\...\Select-String>gc test.txt
---Processing--------------------------
    ---------------------------------------
Installation ID for: Office 19, Office19ProPlus2019MSDNR_Retail edition:
    740589284218418791604841349389902966367300853905012096424324006
    ---------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------
    ---Exiting-----------------------------
PS C:\...\Select-String>(sls '[0-9]+' test.txt -allm).Matches[-1].Value
740589284218418791604841349389902966367300853905012096424324006
PS C:\...\Select-String>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a slightly different method. [*grin*] it presumes the wanted numeric string is the only one in the input, that it is on a line by itself, and that 10 digits is sufficient to exclude unwanted numbers.

what it does ...

- creates an array of strings to work with
  when ready to use real data, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and use `Get-Content` to load the text file.
- defines the minimum number of digits to consider "this is the one"
- uses the way that the `-match` operator works when there is a collection on the left
  instead of giving a boolean, it gives the matching items. in this case there is only the one item.
- trims away any leading/trailing whitespace
- assigns the result to a $Var
- displays the content of that $Var

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
    ---Processing--------------------------
    --------------------------------------- 
Installation ID for: Office 19, Office19ProPlus2019MSDNR_Retail edition:
    740589284218418791604841349389902966367300853905012096424324006
    ---------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------
    ---Exiting-----------------------------
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file

$MinDigits = 10
$BunchaDigits = ($InStuff -match "\d{$MinDigits,}").Trim()

$BunchaDigits
```

output ...

```
740589284218418791604841349389902966367300853905012096424324006
```